# Maintaining order in HashMap

Tags: java

I have a list which I convert to a map to do some work. After that, i convert the map back again to a list, but this time the order is random. I need the same initial order retained in my second list.

the obvious reason is that a HashMap doesn't maintain order. But I need to do something so that it does. I cannot change the Map implementation.How can I do that ?

Consider the given code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dummy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world !");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");list.add("B");list.add("C");
    list.add("D");list.add("E");list.add("F");

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i=i+2)
        map.put(list.get(i),list.get(i+1));

    // Use map here to do some work

    List<String> l= new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry e : map.entrySet()) {
        l.add((String) e.getKey());
        l.add((String) e.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

For ex - Initially, when I printed the list elements, it printed out

```
A B C D E F
```

Now, when I print the elements of `List l`, it printed out

```
E F A B C D
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`HashMap` itself doesn't maintain insertion order - but `LinkedHashMap` does, so use that instead.

As documented... [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

And [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

Comment: Sir, I cannot change the implementation of the map because it is being used at a lot of other places ! Isn't there another way ?

Comment: @OneMoreError: No. It sounds like it's not that you *can't* change the implementation, but that you don't want to. `HashMap` very clearly documents that the order isn't guaranteed - if you're trying to rely on it, then you've basically got a bug which you need to fix. The size of the task doesn't affect whether or not it's a bug you need to fix.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you cannot change the implementation. In these other places, do they actually create a HashMap, or do they only take one as a parameter? You should be programming against the interface, not the implementation. Change them to take a Map as a parameter instead of a HashMap, and then you are free to replace the implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Use **LinkedHashMap** instead of HashMap to maintain order.

```
Map<String,String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: s/LinkedHasMap/LinkedHashMap/

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you change the `Map` implementation (to `LinkedHashMap` for example)?

If there's a logical ordering, you could sort the List with a custom `Comparator`.

Answer (score 1):

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't preserve order of insertion

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you want to preserve order of keys

Answer (score 0):

Consider making your items sortable. In the case of strings, there is already a natural ordering; alphabetical. You can make objects that use the sortable class, and therefore you can use sorting algorithms to put these objects in a nice order, no matter what order you get them in from hash!

Answer (score 0):

It's time for a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), it is meant exactly to preserve insertion order.

Mind that even a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) exists, which allows you to keep your desired order by using Comparable interface. It is not an hash map anymore, but a tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly are unable to switch to another `Map` implementation `(LinkedHashMap` is *exactly* what you want), then the only other possibility is to retain the original `List,` and use it to create the new `List` from the `Map.`

```
public <T> List<T> listFromMapInOrder(final Map<T, T> map, final List<T> order) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T key : order) {
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            result.add(key);
            result.add(map.get(key));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I would refactor the code until it was possible to switch to a `LinkedHashMap.`